# Column cell value in datagridview not aligning with others

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to get the data for each cells to align correctly with each other, but for one column the contents are not lining up with the others. I'm not sure why this is, as I have looked over all the default styles and other layout/appearance options and nothing is out of the ordinary. I don't know if this will help but here is a screenshot of the program running in debug mode.

[image]

It's just the email column that is off for some reason. I can try and provide more information if it is required.

Thanks

I got the rest to line up but still am having trouble with the email columns

[image]

It really is frustrating and makes no sense to me. Would the designer code be useful to take a look at? I can provide it if need be.

Update -

I've noticed its the 4th column (email) on each DGV. Everything else lines up right except for the 4th column. Any ideas?

Update 2 -

Here is the code that is for the datagridview inside the InitializeComponent method:

```
// 
// dataGridView
// 
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle1.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle1;
this.dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
this.dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
this.dataGridView.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle2.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle2;
this.dataGridView.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
this.idDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.firstnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.lastnameDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.phonenumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.birthdayDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.addressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn,
this.marriedDataGridViewTextBoxColumn});
this.dataGridView.DataSource = this.headsBindingSource;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle3.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.DefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle3;
this.dataGridView.GridColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
this.dataGridView.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 63);
this.dataGridView.Name = "dataGridView";
dataGridViewCellStyle4.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle4.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
dataGridViewCellStyle4.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle4.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.WindowText;
dataGridViewCellStyle4.SelectionBackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
dataGridViewCellStyle4.SelectionForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.HighlightText;
dataGridViewCellStyle4.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle4;
dataGridViewCellStyle5.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
dataGridViewCellStyle5.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
dataGridViewCellStyle5.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.RowsDefaultCellStyle = dataGridViewCellStyle5;
this.dataGridView.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
this.dataGridView.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Verdana", 9.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.dataGridView.RowTemplate.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.RowTemplate.Resizable = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTriState.True;
this.dataGridView.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1028, 426);
this.dataGridView.TabIndex = 0;
this.dataGridView.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.dataGridView_KeyDown);
```

and the email column (4th column)

```
// emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
// 
this.emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
this.emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "email_address";
this.emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.HeaderText = "email_address";
this.emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Name = "emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn";
this.emailaddressDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.Width = 125;
//
```

I put the whole solution on dropbox, if anyone can download it and check it out it would be much appreciated - https://www.dropbox.com/s/bh5if8b04eshpo9/QBC%20Members.zip?dl=0

Comment: It seems you have a DPI settings issue right there and the control isn´t rendering well. Try settings DPI to normal to see if the problem persists

Comment: where would that be inside visual studio?

Comment: because I had a similar project to this one and it did not do this.

Comment: all I need is the email column/cell value to be brought down to align with the others

Comment: An out-of-the-box DGV does not exhibit this behavior, so it must've been some change you made. Also, you may want to read the section about **Style Inheritance** [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/cell-styles-in-the-windows-forms-datagridview-control). The problem may be coming from some style other than the cell style.

Comment: yeah, I don't know, I didn't change anything that I haven't changed in a similar project that had the same features and didn't do anything like this. :/

Comment: but thanks for the link

Comment: It is a problem with *code*, not pixels.  Yes, you need to post the code in InitializeComponent().  The minimum required to repro this issue.

Comment: it's a lot of code..

Comment: I posted it all, the code that relates to the dgv

Comment: Is it is possible your data has new lines characters? That will interfere with the alignment as well. Can you try making sure the data trimmed? Also try adding `this.dataGridView1.Columns["Email"].DefaultCellStyle
    .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;` and see if that helps

Comment: not that I know of, its just bound to a sql server table. I tried that code sample you gave and sadly didn't work. I don't know what's going on.

Comment: it's only the email column that isn't being aligned. I need it to come down.

Comment: Use your debugger and inspect the value for `dataGridView1.Columns[4].InheritedStyle.Alignment`.

Comment: it says Middle Left

Comment: funny thing is that when I go to print it, the columns are aligned perfectly, it's only in the DGV that it is off

Comment: The inspection should happen **after** the misalignment in question is in full display on the screen. And while you're at it, inspect as well the same value for all 6 styles mentioned in the article linked above, for non-header cells.

Comment: It is, it's after the data grid has been filled with the data from the bound source (sql server). All styles are the same, I triple checked every one, even the non header cells.

Comment: would it help any if you could take a look at the actual solution?

Comment: Sure, post it somewhere, but I can't handle zip files, only plain source code.

Comment: If everything else fails, try this: do **not** explicitly create any columns, simply assign `dataGridView1.DataSource` with a collection of your data model and let the dgv auto-generate it for you.

Comment: It is auto generated, the columns come from the database

Comment: do you have dropbox? I could share it with you there?

Comment: Sorry man, I can't do that....

Comment: okay, no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the autosizing of rows to false and added padding and it fixed the alignment issues. Not exactly what I was hoping for but it'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Email"].DefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

and for header:

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[4].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sad to hear it didn't work, but also double check your datagridview properties it might something as simple as the alignment values.

Comment: i checked them all and they are the same (middle left). not sure what is going on..

Comment: funny thing is that when I go to print it, the columns are aligned perfectly, it's only in the DGV that it is off